# running Apache as a particular user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Sorry I'm a total noob when it comes to rails, Linux & Apache. In IIS you can set the credentials for the app pool. Is there something similar in the Apache world. I have a rails app and I plan to Use passenger to deploy my site.

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy mechanisms. The first is to start Apache as the user that you want it to run as. This is nice, as it never involves `root` access. The downside is that you cannot bind to low ports (<1024) -- including the default port, `80`.

The second mechanism is to use the [`User` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user):

```
User apache
```

or

```
User www
```

Or whatever -- make sure the account exists in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` (`adduser(8)` makes adding users easy). You can also use a userid *number*, but this is far less common.